# Chrome extension's content script not getting injected on specific websites

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a basic chrome extension that appends some DOM elements to the website's HTML body. I'm using content scripts to achieve this. It is working fine on most websites, but on few (especially on net-banking websites), content script is not getting executed.

My question is, can a website block content script to inject any code into its webpage (as part of security measure or something)? If so, is there any other alternative? I tried using background script that programmatically executes content scripts, but background script is not getting executed each time a load a new page.

Comment: Could you please provide more details, such as your sample code and websites url? And does the websites dom contains iframe? I mean maybe you didn't include all_frames in your manifest file...

Comment: I'm sorry the code is confidential so cannot share! But yes, the websites on which its not working contain iframes! I was trying "match_about_blank" set to true, but wasn't succeeding. "all_frame" solved my issue!:) Thanks a ton Haibara Ai!:)

Comment: I have dup the comments as an answer, please mark it accepted in case of unresolved questions. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure if these websites contain iframe. If so, you need to add the following in your manifest.json.

```
"all_frames": true
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your manifest.json with below permission

```
 "content_scripts": [{
                            "matches"       :   ["https://specificURL/*","https://*/*","http://*/*"],
                             "all_frames"   :   true
                        }]
```